# Does Sitecore 8 keep role based security

Tags: sitecore

I used Sitecore actively from version 5 through 7, but haven't had to work with it for over 2 years now.  A colleague of mine was asking about security because he had heard an assertion that item permissions must be assigned on a user by user basis and there is no concept of role.  I can definitively answer from experience and documentation that Sitecore version 7 and below both allowed and highly encouraged conforming to the generally accepted best practice of assigning access based on role/group and cannot imagine a world where they would have gone away from that in version 8, but have no documentation or actual experience with version 8 to definitively say it still supports role based security.  Is there someone who is currently working with version 8 that can confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Sitecore 8 supports role based security and it is a good practice to define security based on roles instead of users.

Comment: Thank you for verifying this - I couldn't imagine otherwise, but don't like to speak based on assumption.